# perl iterate forloop over an array with path that matches condition

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to print the paths on my linux system which are mentioned in a perl array. How can add an array element which will print list of paths which starts with `cox/m3` and have a subdirectory named `foo`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @excludepaths = (
  "abc/def/",
  "hij/klm/", 
  "cox/m3/*/foo/",  
);

foreach (@excludepaths) {
  print "$_\n";
    }
    exit 1;
```

Current Output:

```
abc/def/
hij/klm/
cox/m3/*/foo/
```

Desired Output:

```
abc/def/
hij/klm/
cox/m3/fsdf/dsgsdfg/fgf/foo/
cox/m3/weret/wer/foo/
```

Comment: Are you trying to search a directory? You don't invoke `readdir` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @excludepaths = (
  "abc/def/",
  "hij/klm/", 
  "cox/m3/*/foo/",  
);

chdir '/path/to/root/dir';

foreach my $path (@excludepaths) {
  foreach (glob $path) {
    print "$_\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: are the directories in the current directory where script is run?

Comment: No, they are in different location...I want to list all the paths which starts with `cox/m3` and have `foo` as sub-directory

Comment: try the updated - change '/path/to/root/dir' to your directory where you want to check paths

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is - you're not doing any directory searching at all. So all you're doing is printing array elements, which is why you're getting what you're getting.

If you're wanting to use 'shell style' syntax to expand, then you want `glob`. But I'd suggest instead - consider using `File::Find` and use regular expressions:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my @excludepaths = qw (
  abc/def/
  hij/klm/
  cox/m3/.*/foo/
);

## NB - switched to regular expression, not '*'

my $is_match = join ( "|", map { quotemeta } @excludepaths );
   $is_match = qr/($is_match)/;

sub print_if_match {
    return unless -d;
    if ( $File::Find::name =~ m/$is_match/ ) {
        print "$File::Find::name\n"; 
    }
}

find ( \&print_if_match, "/path/to/search", "../path_to_search/2" );
```

Comment: @Sorbique What should I replace in `"/path/to/search", "../path_to_search/2"` ?

Comment: That's just a list of paths to look in. So... whatever path you want to look in. (Illustrated as `File::Find` supports multiple).

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @excludepath = ("abc/def/","hij/klm/","cox/m3/*/foo/");

foreach (@excludepath) {
    system("find $_ -type d");
}
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using system `find` over perl's built in `File::Find`?

Comment: I personally prefer to use system commands because I think they are easier although some people prefer to avoid using them because they are system specific meaning using File::Find you may be able to use your script on linux and windows machines where the system command is going to be OS dependent.

Comment: Fair enough. I tend to think sticking with the 'built in' wherever possible is "better style" but I can understand that view.